# Show that $f(x) = \cos(2x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x) = \cos(2x)$. Show that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Mt attempt:

We have, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0, s.t.\mid x-y \mid < \delta \implies | f(x) - f(y) |=|\cos(2x) - \cos(2y)|=| -2\sin(x-y)\sin(x+y)| \leq 2|\sin(x-y)|\leq 2| x-y|$

Now, since $|x-y| \leq \delta, 2| x-y| <2\delta,$ 
 $$2| \sin(x-y)| <2\delta.$$ Let, $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Rightarrow 2|\sin(x-y)|<2\delta=\epsilon$

Am I on the right track? The only place I am confused here is the domain. What is the purpose of defining this from $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$? All I did here is, manipulated the trigonometric identity. I don't understand where did I use the domain  in this case? If this is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, then isn't it continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$? Or, would that be different than this? Or, maybe I am doing this the wrong way, am I? I am just all confused with the domain part. any details would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is continuous  on the closed bounded interval $[0,\pi]$ and therefore uniformly continuous on that interval. By periodicity it is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Your proof is fine, although you can just use the MVT to show that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is Lipschitz and hence uniformly continuous in all of $\Bbb R$. Given $x,y \in \Bbb R$, by the Mean Value Theorem there exists $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that: $$|\cos(2x)-\cos(2y)| = |2\sin(2z)||x-y| \leq 2|x-y|,$$since $\sin$ is a bounded function. Given $\epsilon > 0$, $\delta = \epsilon/2> 0$ will always work. The requirement of the domain being $[0,+\infty[$ instead of $\Bbb R$ is superfluous...

Comment: Sorry, but we still haven't learned the connection between Lipchitz and uniform continuity yet. So, I am a bit behind on this :)

Comment: @Jellyfish: This answer has shown you a way independent of really knowing the Lipschitz stuff! Using mean-value theorem suffices.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned Lipschitz continuity if that caused confusion. The Mean Value Theorem suffices. But it is very simple, I can explain to you here in this comment: a function is Lipschitz if there exists $M > 0$ such that: $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|, \quad \forall\,x,y\in {\rm dom}(f).$$Every Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous: given $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \epsilon/M > 0$. So if $|x-y|<\delta$, we have: $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M |x-y|< M\frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon.$$Finally, every differentiable function with bounded derivative is Lipschitz and so uniformly continuous

Comment: (Wow, I used all the characters allowed!)

Comment: Wow, that completely close to what I did there. Maybe I should've looked on that first.

Comment: The trick "MVT + bounded derivative" is neat, it's worth keeping it..

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next time.